# How to add attributes to elements after dynamically adding them to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm using fetch to dynamically add elements from local json file to the DOM and then I want to add draggable attributes to it. Here's the code:

```
function addHeroes() {
  fetch('superheroes.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let output = "";
      data.forEach(function(item) {
        output += `<li>${item.name}</li>`;
      });
      $(".superheroes").append(output);
    })
};

function addDraggables() {
  $(".superheroes li").attr({
    draggable: "true",
    ondragstart: "drag(event)"
  });
};
```

I cannot add any attribute in those list items in unordered list 'superheroes' after manipulating DOM. However, I can see the list items appear in the inspector.

Comment: Why not just write it into the items? `<li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">${item.name}</li>` assuming it's the list items you are trying to target?

Comment: why not adding the id while adding them to DOM? After that, you can target by id.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : the "refresh" didnt work, try this :

```js
function addHeroes() {
  fetch('superheroes.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.forEach(function(item) {
        let li = $('<li></li>');
        li.text(item.name);
        li.attr({
         draggable: "true",
         ondragstart: "drag(event)"
        });
        $(".superheroes").append(li);
      });
      
    })
};
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).listview is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to solve your problem

one solution is to use class attribute on the li element and use it to select the elements and then call the method look at the example below or use any selector to select the element except the **id** selector because it should be unique

```js
function addHeroes() {
  fetch('superheroes.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let output = "";
      data.forEach(function(item) {
        output += `<li class='drag-item'>${item.name}</li>`;
      });
      $(".superheroes").append(output);
      addDraggables();
    })
};

function addDraggables() {
  $(".drag-item").attr({
    draggable: "true",
    ondragstart: "drag(event)"
  });
};
```

another option is to select all elements in **superheros** list and call the method  like the example below

```js
function addHeroes() {
  fetch('superheroes.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let output = "";
      data.forEach(function(item) {
        output += `<li class='drag-item'>${item.name}</li>`;
      });
      $(".superheroes").append(output);
      addDraggables();
    })
};

function addDraggables() {
  // select the last element in the list 
  $(".superheroes li").attr({
    draggable: "true",
    ondragstart: "drag(event)"
  });
};
```

also another option is to put the attributes directly in the elements like the example below

```js
function addHeroes() {
  fetch('superheroes.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let output = "";
      data.forEach(function(item) {
        output += "<li draggable='true' ondragstart ='drag(event)'>${item.name}</li>";
      });
      $(".superheroes").append(output);
    })
};

function addDraggables() {
  $(".superheroes").attr({
    draggable: "true",
    ondragstart: "drag(event)"
  });
};
```

Copy any one of them and try it in your code

Comment: Thanks man, it solved my problem by just calling the "addDraggables" method directly from "addHeroes" instead from "$(function () {" after DOM load.

I wonder why it doesn't work when I call the addDraggables directly after the DOM load?